# $this is a reference to an object?

Tags: php

I understand that this "refers" to the current object but it is not the actual object.  How exactly does `$this` refer to the object.  Is `$this` a pointer to the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` is a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).
From the PHP manual:

> References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by
>   different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you
>   cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual
>   memory addresses, and so on. See [What References Are Not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php) for more
>   information. Instead, they are symbol table aliases. Note that in PHP,
>   variable name and variable content are different, so the same content
>   can have different names. The closest analogy is with Unix filenames
>   and files - variable names are directory entries, while variable
>   content is the file itself. References can be likened to hardlinking
>   in Unix filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object
>   (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another
>   object, if the method is called statically from the context of a
>   secondary object).

[References are not pointers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php)

Comment: I understand `$this` is a reference.  But how does it reference the object?  Is `$this` a pointer to the object?

Comment: No, references are not pointers. Check the link.